# How to copy files from Azure File Storage to Azure VM in release pipeline TFS?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there any built-in TFS build task or PowerShell script to copy files from Azure File Storage to Azure VM via release deployment pipeline in TFS. I tried looking a bit on internet but didn't get anything fruitful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we do not have this kind of build-in task. We have a [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) which use it copy application files and other artifacts to Microsoft Azure storage blobs or virtual machines (VMs).

> When the target is Azure VMs, the files are first copied to an
>   automatically generated Azure blob container and then downloaded into
>   the VMs. The container is deleted after the files have been
>   successfully copied to the VMs.

You could use **AzCopy command** on the VM to copy/download data from blob to local driver.

1. Install AzCopy from http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy
2. Read docs from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy
3. cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"
4. Get Blob Storage (Secondary) Key
5. ### Powershell: Blob Upload single file

```
    .\AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfolder/ /DestKey:key /Pattern:abc.txt
```

6. Logon to Remote VM
7. ### Powershell: Blob Download single file

```
    .\AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/myfolder/ /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceKey:key /Pattern:abc.txt
```

For PowerShell, you need to use PowerShell Core 6.x and later on all platforms. It works with Windows and Linux virtual machines using Windows PowerShell 5.1 (Windows only) or PowerShell 6 (Windows and Linux).

You can find the PowerShell commands in this document: [Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs by using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#upload-blobs-to-the-container)

Comment: I need to do directly from Azure File Storage to Azure VM using Release deployment pipeline. I don't want to login to Azure VM and manually copy file using AZ copy.

Comment: Hi Naveen Kumar, sorry for not make it clearly. For now there is not any task could handle this like directly copy files from A to B in azure devops release deployment pipeline. You have to create your own extension and  simulate  a user connect to Azure VM , finally download/copy file from Blob to local driver in Azure VM by using AzCopy command line.

Comment: Hi Naveen, any update on this thread, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu, I have wrote my own custom script and added PowerShell as a task in Release Pipeline, it's all automated now, thanks for help.

Comment: I am also looking for same Powershell script, can you please share.

Comment: what a pity there is no built-in task for such an obvious functionality! We use custom build server and had to install components there to make this work